# grep to get <div> content

Tags: bash, grep

Assume i have a file ***t1.txt***

`<div class="content"> main </div> <div class="data"> 100 </div>`

If i run

```
grep -o "content.*</div>" t1.txt
```

it will return

```
content"> main </div> <div class="data"> 100 </div>
```

How can i grep the text by the 1st encountered `</div>`? i want to get

```
content"> main </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `*` is greedy it is not trivial to match until the first `</div>` with a single grep. You can use Perl lazy quantifier `*?`:

```
perl -lane '{print $1 if m!(content.*?</div>)!}' input
```

You can also modify the grep expression slightly, but it will be less flexible:

```
grep -o 'content">[^>]*</div>' input
```

Comment: this is a brilliant idea!

Answer (score 2):

Use a lazy match:

```
grep -P -o 'content.*?</div>' t1.txt
```

You need the `-P` flag to use perl syntax, since grep doesn't support lazy matching by default.

Editorial note: parsing HTML with regular expressions is not really a great idea most of the time.

Comment: seems like -P is not available by default.. i'm using Mac OSX

Comment: `-P` is a GNU grep feature, I think.